# Only abelian group with these properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Consider an abelian group $G=\{e_0, \ldots, e_n\}$ with $|G|=n+1$ elements such that $$2^j e_j=0, \, \forall \; 0\leq j\leq n.$$

I.e. $e_0=0$ is the identity element. Furthermore, $2e_1=0$, $4e_2=0, \ldots $ are all equal to the identity.

Does $G$ exist and must $G$ be unique?

Answer (score 3):

If $n + 1$ is a power of $2$ then any abelian $2$-group of order $n+1$ will work. There is at least one $2$-torsion element not equal to the identity, at least one $4$-torsion element not equal to the $2$-torsion element already picked, etc.

Otherwise the result is false since the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds for abelian groups and so if there is an odd number dividing $n + 1$ then no such group can exist.

Note that if you require the order of $e_j$ to be *exactly* $2^j$ (rather than the requirement that $2^je_j = 0$) then the result is false for $n + 1 > 2$, since $e_2$ and $-e_2$ have the same order.